# Slim CD with Account Number and Routing Number

Tags: php

I have searched through the google for finding out slim cd payment using account number and routing number using PHP. I didn't get any helpful resources can anyone help me out to resolve this issue?

```
include 'slimcd.php';

// Create the Slim CD object
$SlimCD = new SlimCD() ;

// Create a ProcessTransaction Request class
$request = new Transact_ProcessTransactionRequest() ;
$request->username = '1032';
$request->password = '289075';
$request->clientid = '1032';
$request->siteid = 228226448 ;
$request->priceid = 74 ;
$request->transtype = 'SALE' ;
$request->amount = '10.00' ;
$request->cardnumber = '4111111111111111' ;
$request->expmonth = '12' ;
$request->expyear = '49' ;
$request->product = 'MyPHP' ;
$request->ver = '1.0' ;
$request->key = 'SVD-072-5QQ6-5K58' ;
$reply = $SlimCD->Transact_ProcessTransaction($request);
echo var_dump($reply) ;
```

this is for credit card transaction. i need code for debit for the account.

I try the below code. I got the below mentioned issue.

```
function accPay()
{
    $SlimCD = new SlimCD() ;
    $request = new Transact_ProcessTransactionRequest() ;
    $request->username = '1032';
    $request->password = '289075';
    $request->clientid = '1032';
    $request->siteid = 228226448;
    $request->priceid = 74;
    $request->transtype = "SALE";
    $request->amount = "10" ;
    $request->accountno = "1111111111";
    $request->routeno = "222222222";
    $request->product = 'MyPHP';
    $request->ver = '1.0';
    $request->key = 'SVD-072-5QQ6-5K58';
    $reply = $SlimCD->Transact_ProcessTransaction($request);
    return $reply;
}



 {"response":"Error","responsecode":2,"description":"*--NEED_EXPMONTH--NEED_EXPYEAR--NEED_CARDNUMBER.","responseurl":"http:\/\/stats.slimcd.com\/wswebservices\/transact.asmx\/ProcessTransaction","datablock":{"authcode":"","approved":"E","cvv2reply":"","avsreply":"","gateid":0,"bankid":null,"corporatecardindicator":"","invoiceno":"","firstname":"","lastname":"","cardtype":"","last4":"","expmonth":"","expyear":"","processor_token":"","emvreplytags":"","approvedhsaamt":null,"approvedamt":0,"bal":null,"returncheckservicecharge":null}}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Plz provide some code

Comment: added some code. Thanks

Comment: I hope those usernames and passwords you posted aren't important.

Comment: yes. those are sample one posted in the website